# Google analytics tracking www and no-www domains

Tags: domains, google-analytics, no-www

Our website is set up to direct all traffic for `www.example.com` to example.com with a line in the htaccess file.  With Google analytics new in page analytics feature we are thinking of removing the line and allowing people to visit `www.example.com` as well to play with the new features.  My question is this.  How will this change affect our analytics data.

- Will nothing change and we can start using the new feature with our existing data
- Are the two domains tracked separately and we will have to start over with `www.example.com`

Any help would be great, as I can find nothing on Google help sites covering this. Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: Im not really sure why you would want to do this, cant you just enable, the new inpage features on your existing GA account ?

Comment: Both sub-domains will be considered as separate by Google and you can add both of them as different sites in GA.

Answer (score 1):

You need note worry about this. In Google Analytics, simply go to the Tracking settings in the Admin section, and enable the multiple subdomain tracking. That way GA will track visits coming to www.example.com and example.com separately and report them to you in the same property.

What you can also do, is use the canonical tag to define which version to use.